# Will creating a directory inside a system directory with 777 permission cause security vulnerability?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, security, directory, vulnerability

Can creating directories with 777 permission inside system directories cause any security weakness?

For example, say I open a directory called **`Custom`** inside `/usr/share/backgrounds/` and give it 777 permission. Is it going to create any kind of security vulnerability?

Comment: Every time you do `chmod 777`, somewhere in the world a kitten dies

Comment: @janos LOL. Tell me if my cat wallpapers can be automatically deleted by some naughty person or program ;)

Comment: You kitten murderer @LonelyKing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs to be answered with NO. For it to become an issue: someone first needs to gain access to your machine. If there is no way for someone to gain access exploiting it will be impossible. You do not mention having a web server active. You do not mention this machine being connected to the internet. So the answer is no.

Still ...   WHY would you need 777 for a directory inside "/usr/share/backgrounds/? There is absolutely NO reason for it. 775 is more than enough.

And it should be noted that not using 777 is the better approach. Thing is... in 1/2 a years time you consider using a web server on your machine. Of course you totally forgot about doing setting a directory to 777 and oops it is inside your virtual host... 
It would be rather easy to drop a script inside that directory that scans for files that contains the password to your MySQL server.

Comment: Awww right. Well, I was just asking in a general sense out of curiosity. Thanks :)

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote please? AFAIK I am correct with this.